# Is there a way to override the resources section with a profile in maven?

Tags: java, maven

After trying for a while I noticed the `<resources>` are not overridden if there is a profile that contains the same `<directory>`, for example:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>dir1/**.json</exclude>
                    <exclude>dir2/*.sh</exclude>
       
                </excludes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
       <!-- plugins and other stuff-->
</build>
```

If want to have something different in another profile:

```
<profile>
            <id>ci</id>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <excludes>
                             <exclude>dir1/**.json</exclude>
                            <exclude>dir1/*.js</exclude>
                             <exclude>dir1/*.css</exclude>
                             <exclude>dir2/*.sh</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
           </build>
</profile>
```

`maven clean package -Pci` seems to ignore the resources specified in the profile, and works the same as without the profile.

Any suggestions to work around this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maven **adds** the profile `resources` section to the main one. The effective `pom` will be

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>dir1/**</exclude>
                <exclude>dir2/*.sh</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>dir3/**</exclude>
                <exclude>dir4/*.css</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
   <!-- plugins and other stuff-->
</build>
```

I think the best would be to put the custom resources under different folders, e.g `ci-resources` and `non-ci-resources` and to define 2 profiles `ci` and `non-ci`

```
<profile>
        <id>ci</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/ci-resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
       </build>
</profile>
<profile>
        <id>non-ci</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/non-ci-resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
       </build>
```

and whenever you need a resource from either profile you can just activate the profile

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve my issue. The files happen to be in same folder (sorry if the example is misleading, I edited now), and therefore the need to override. I have a javascript app that I compile with over ~5MB size. I want to be able to strip those files out of the jar, because I use them only in dev environment.

Comment: @zakariaamine you can not override resources elements, you must use different profiles  with different includes/excludes

Answer (score 0):

If there are only limited files, I would rather go with `<include>`. It follows like this:

```
resources
   |
   |__ dir1
        |_ dir1file.txt
        |_ dir1file2.txt
```

So, profile *dev* includes only *dir1/dir1file.txt*, while profile *test* includes *dir1/dir1file2.txt*.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>dir1/dir1file.txt</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
         <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>dir1/dir1file2.txt</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

[image: dev profile]

[image: test profile]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried but it did not solve my issue. I have overlapping elements that should be in both profiles

Comment: what do you mean by overlapping, and what does that have to do with the inclusion? please enlighten me

Comment: I compile a js application that has random suffixes, and therefore the names are not static. I just need to use *.js. In the dev profile, I need to keep everything (*.js and *html), but in prod I use a cdn, therefore I want to trip off the *.js and keep the *.html, to save to megs on the final JAR.

Comment: You could use a pattern then, *dir1/\*.js* and/or *dir1/\*.html*